# julia-lang - Convert image to black and white

Tags: image-processing, julia

I'm trying to transform an image to black & white using Julia with threshold is 0.5. I've converted the image to grayscale, but not sure if that helps. I'm new to Julia so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please provide an example of your input and the specification of desired output?
In general if `x` is a matrix of `Float64` containing your gray scale image then `Float64.(x .> 0.5)` will give you what you want. For example:

```
julia> img = rand(5,4)
5×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.294821  0.719161   0.36838    0.0962881
 0.262626  0.0169155  0.7068     0.668797
 0.450861  0.493318   0.0125666  0.783241
 0.267667  0.652534   0.0860362  0.811446
 0.586622  0.08407    0.316635   0.36396

julia> Float64.(img .> 0.5)
5×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

If you wanted to specify explicitly target values (the code above uses the fact that `true` gets converted to `1.0` and `false` to `0.0`) you can write:

```
julia> ifelse.(img .> 0.5, 1.0, 0.0)
5×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

You can achieve this result also using comprehensions:

```
julia> Float64[v > 0.5 for v in img]
5×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

julia> [ifelse(v > 0.5, 1.0, 0.0) for v in img]
5×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

try with the following code snippet:

```
using Images, ImageView;

function show_binary_image(img_path::String, threshold::Float16)
    img_binary = load(img_path);
    img_binary = (Gray.(img_binary) .> threshold);
    imshow(img_binary);
end

show_binary_image("/path/to/image/file", convert(Float16, 0.5));
```